# haproxy tcp transparent mode on the same box as service

Tags: tcp, haproxy, localhost

I'd like to set up transparent HA Proxy for TCP protocol.
It works flawlessly when HA Proxy is in front of the boxes that are running the service.
But when I try to set up HA Proxy in transparent mode to load balance connections to a service that is residing on the same box as HA Proxy then it stops working.

My actual setup looks like this:

eth0 192.168.56.101

**HA Proxy config:**

listen sftp :9222
        mode tcp
    source 0.0.0.0 usesrc clientip
    option tcpka
    option tcplog
        balance leastconn
        server server1 192.168.56.101:22 check

**IPTABLES/ROUTING:**
iptables -t mangle -N DIVERT
iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j ACCEPT
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m socket -j DIVERT
ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100
ip route add local default dev eth0 table 100

It looks like an issue with routing. I've tried lots of rules/scenarios but I'm unable to get it working. Please advise.

Regards,
Filip